# SearchView working code explanation

Tags: android, listview

I have made a simple app and in it i have used a searchview.
The searchview code has been copied from a youtube link, and I haven't fully understood it. Could someone explain it clearly with the explanation of how all the functions work?

The id of the listview is ListView1 and the id of the searchview is searchview1.

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchview1);

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.android.layout.simple_list_item_1, *array name*);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener()) {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onQueryChange(String text) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Could someone please provide line by line explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all information using http://developer.android.com. In this case you are looking for [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) and [SearchView.OnQueryTextListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html).

First you need to attach `OnQueryTextListener` callback to `SearchView` which gives you information what user is doing:

- `onQueryTextSubmit` informs you when the query text is changed by the user, returns false if the `SearchView` should perform the default action of showing any suggestions if available, true if the action was handled by the listener
- `onQueryTextSubmit` is called when the user submits the query, returns true if the query has been handled by the listener, false to let the SearchView perform the default action

In `onQueryChange` your are using `ArrayAdapter`'s `Filter` class to filter your list. If you would like to know how to `Filter` performs filtering you can check [`ArrayFilter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#410).

Comment: Thanks, but what do those return statements indicate?

Comment: @lPing7 - if you handled query by yourself this method should return true, false otherwise.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean by handling it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

java

```
public class SearchViewFilterMode extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

     SearchView mSearchView;
    private ListView mListView;

    private final String[] mStrings = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;

    @Override
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.searchview_filter);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mStrings));
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true); 
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    }

    public onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: @lPing7 just try with that code..and if any error is there let me know